# Set, definition of subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, definition

I was given this proposition by definition $S \subseteq T \iff S \subset T \lor S = T$.

But the righthand side makes no sense to me: how can including $\lor S$ to something that already includes $T$ make it equal to $T$ ?

Thank you

Comment: it means $S \subset$ OR $S = T$

Comment: The right hand side should be read $S\subset T$ or $S=T$. The symbol $\lor$ is logical or.

Comment: Humm I guess I have mixed $\lor$ and $\cup$. My bad.

Comment: Here is an example $\{0\}\cup\{0,1\} = \{0,1\}$

Comment: how can including S to something that already includes T make it equal to T? $S$ does not includes $T$ - the converse is true, $T$ includes $S$!!

Comment: Yeah my wording was not right. English is not my native tongue. I wished to say : " that is already include in T make it equal to T". My error was to mix $\lor$ and $\cup$.

Comment: The symbols $S\subset T \lor S=T$ means $(S\subset T) \lor (S=T) $. They do not mean $(S\subset T \lor S)=T $.  The phrase $S\subset T\lor S $ doesn't make an grammatical sense, either true or false.